# Proving $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ where $F$ is a field and $a,b\in F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, inverse

Proving $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ where $F$ is a field and $a,b\in F$.

One thing to note is $a^{-1}\ne \large\frac{1}{a}$ (same goes for $b$) in this instance as there could be fields where this isn't true.

Just before this I did a similar problem where I needed to prove $(-a)^{-1}=-(a^{-1})$.
What I did there was:

$$-(a^{-1})\cdot (-a)=a^{-1}\cdot (-(-a))=a^{-1}a=1$$

So $-(a^{-1})$ is the multiplicative inverse of $-a$.

The problem I am having is finding an appropriate way similar to the last problem that doesn't involve using $\large\frac{1}{a}$ that I'm not allowed to use.

Comment: I forget... Does $ba=ab$ in any given field, or does abelian apply to fields as well as groups?

Comment: So, we still have $a^{-1}\cdot a=a\cdot a^{-1}=1$ correct?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, yes to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean $a,b$ are nonzero.

It's important to remember that $(ab)^{-1}$ is **by definition** the unique element $c$ such that $c(ab)=(ab)c=1$. So to show $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$, you just need to show $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ satisfies the role of the element $c$ in the previous sentence.

This follows from associativity, 
$$
(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1})=a(bb^{-1})a^{-1}=aa^{-1}=1
$$
and similarly $(b^{-1}a^{-1})(ab)=1$. So by definition, $b^{-1}a^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}$.

Comment: $a^{-1}\ne \large\frac{1}{a}$ for any field. For example: in $\mathbb Z_{13}, \large\frac{1}{[7]_{13}}\ne ([7]_{13})^{-1}$ it's $[2]_{13}$.

Comment: @Vincent What does $\frac{1}{[7]_{13}}$ mean if not the multiplicative inverse of $7$ modulo $13$?

Comment: I should say that $([7]_{13})^{-1}=[2]_{13}$, to be clear.

Comment: @Vincent Right, but $\frac{1}{[7]_{13}}=[2]_{13}$ as well.

Comment: Hmm. Looking at my notes I see "Fractional notation can be ambiguous in a noncommutative example". It went on to give an example using the Quaternions. I couldn't definitively tell you why. I just have what my professor has said. You may be right in that it should be interchangeable and that it just isn't in practice. You wouldn't write $\large\frac{1}{[7]_{13}}$, you'd write $[2]_{13}$.

Comment: If I found out a more concrete reason why, I'll write it here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Vincent: Fields are commutative by definition. The quaternions do not form a field, only a "skew field".

Answer (score 1):

$$(ab)^{-1}(ab)=e \\ \implies (ab)^{-1}ab=e \\ \implies (ab)^{-1}abb^{-1}=b^{-1}\\ \implies (ab)^{-1}a=b^{-1} \\ \implies (ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$$

Comment: Exactly what I was getting at...

Comment: Is it inappropriate to use $1$ instead of $e$?

Comment: I think both are okay to use. The $1$ can be used to symbolize the identity element. It doesn't necessarily mean that $1$ is the identity. For that reason I prefer to use $e$.